# moment.js: how to initialize from DD/MM/YYYY format

Tags: momentjs

I want to initilize moment from DD/MM/YYYY format
ex:

```
var xmas = moment('25/12/2016'); //does not work


var xmas = moment('2016-12-25');// works
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you just had to scroll the docs down a bit to the String + Format section

```js
var xmas = moment('25/12/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: ... and this work with [Localized format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#localized-formats) `'L'`